# Is this right approach to call an API?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I want to know if what I've written below is the correct approach to make a request to an API. If not please help and suggest anything that is not correct.

```js
function readQuoteFromRSS(rssUrl) {
  fetch(rssUrl).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(response) {
    setStore(response);
  });
}
```

Comment: See [this blog post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) from the wonderful [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's mostly fine, except that unfortunately it's falling prey to the `fetch` API footgun I describe in [the link Ivar gave you](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) — `fetch` only rejects its promise on *network* errors, not HTTP errors like 404 or 500. So you have to check for HTTP errors on the response object.

A couple of other things:

1. It's important to either handle rejection or return the promise chain from the function so the caller can (usually you want to do the latter, but if this is an entry point like an event handler, there's nowhere to pass it to and you have to handle it locally).
2. I probably wouldn't use `response` for the name of the parameter in the last `then`, since it won't be a Response object anymore as it was in the previous handler. Perhaps `data`.

```
function readQuoteFromRSS(rssUrl) {
    return fetch(rssUrl)                                          // *** return
        .then(function (response) {
            if (!response.ok) {                                   // *** check
                throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`); // *** for HTTP
            }                                                     // *** error
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            setStore(data);
        });
}
```

---

Purely as a matter of style, since modern environments support `async`/`await`, I'd probably use it:

```
async function readQuoteFromRSS(rssUrl) {
    const response = await fetch(rssUrl);
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    setStore(data);
}
```